# Upload Image via Graph API & "Missing or invalid image file"

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

My problem is image url some time not working. It show error "Missing or invalid image file" when submit image url like this "http://www.webdoanhnghiep.biz/Templates/img/FacebookAmplifier.jpg". Then, if I try to refresh,clear cached.... and submit again. It work.

```
var params = {};
params['message'] = messageWillPost;
    params['url'] = 'http://www.webdoanhnghiep.biz/Templates/img/FacebookAmplifier.jpg';

params['place'] = document.getElementById(locationSelectionClientID).value;

FB.api('/' + postToAlbumId + '/photos','post',params, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
        console.log(response.error.message);
    } else {
        var photoId = response.id;
        console.log("Post to facebook at: " + photoId);
    }
});
```

WHY DOES THIS HAPPEN? How to void?
Thanks you

Comment: My issue was that the image wasn't at least 180 pixels in width. I spent hours trying to figure this out, silly Facebook errors.